# Permission Denied when running BASH that downloads and runs External Script

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I am trying to make a script that I can use to update a custom linux product automatically. 
This first script is being made on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, but I also have some of my product running on older laptops that are running debian.
Currently I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget --mirror --continue --no-host-directories http://somedomain.com/dir1/dir2/webscript.bash;
if /home/mr/dir1/dir2/webscript.bash;
then
        chmod 777 /home/mr/dir1/dir2/webscript.bash;
        bash /home/mr/dir1/dir2/webscript.bash;
fi
        rm /home/mr/dir1/dir2/webscript.bash;
sleep 10;
```

I get the file downloaded but get an error that permission is denied.

```
./script.sh: 4: ./script.sh: /home/mr/dir1/dir2/webscript.bash: Permission denied
```

Comment: Can u share with us the error message?

Comment: Maybe the permission denied error is something of your script you downloaded and trying execute. you can try running as root and see if the error appears.

Comment: After getting message about successful download of file I get ./script.sh: 4: ./script.sh: /home/mr/dir1/dir2/webscript.bash: Permission denied

Comment: Try to put /bin/chmod 777 /home/mr.... after then

Comment: adding /bin/chmod didn't change the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess u want to check if file exists then run it..add "-f" ->

```
if [ -f /home/mr/dir1/dir2/webscript.bash ];
then
    chmod 777 /home/mr/dir1/dir2/webscript.bash;
    bash /home/mr/dir1/dir2/webscript.bash;
fi
    rm /home/mr/dir1/dir2/webscript.bash;
sleep 10;
```

Comment: You were basically running that script in the if condition instead of checking the file existence..

Answer (score 0):

Put chmod +x on your file downloaded

Comment: Everything must be done from within the script. Changing my chmod from 777 to +x didnt change the error.